# About get_special_tokens_mask in huggingface-transformers

Tags: tokenize, huggingface-transformers

I use transformers tokenizer, and created mask using API: get_special_tokens_mask.
[My Code](https://github.com/ishikawa-takumi/transformers-sample/blob/master/tokenizer.ipynb)

In [RoBERTa Doc](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html), returns of this API is "A list of integers in the range [0, 1]: 0 for a special token, 1 for a sequence token". But I seem that this API returns "0 for a sequence token, 1 for a special token".
Is it all right?

Comment: Which version of tokenizers are  you using? Also, please include an [mcve] of your problem, which explains the problem *without* any external code sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed correct. I tested this for both transformers 2.7 and the (at the time of writing) current release of 2.9, and in both cases I do get the  inverted results  (`0` for regular characters, and `1` for the special characters.

For reference, this is how I tested it:

```py
import transformers

tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
sentence = "This is a special sentence."

encoded_sentence = tokenizer.encode(sentence)
# [0, 152, 16, 10, 780, 3645, 4, 2]
special_masks = tokenizer.get_special_tokens_mask(encoded_sentence)
# [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I would suggest you report this issue in [their repository](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers), or ideally provide a pull request yourself to fix the issue ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will report this issue.